# Jquery horizontal slider not working firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
<div id="animate" style="position: fixed; top: 150px; right: -1000px; width: 100%;height: 300px;"><A HREF="http://www.example.nl"><img src="http://www.example.nl/img/test.png"></a></div>
<script>
 $('#animate').animate({
right: '2000px',
}, 50000, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
</script>
```

Problem with this script is that if i run it in Chrome, it will slide from right to left.
But as soon as i want to run it in FireFox, he is freezing, and not moving at all.

Thanks in forehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `#animate` to `position: absolute;` This should fix your problem!

edit: i provided a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YbXED/2/) works good on firefox 21.

Comment: have a look at my edit! you set your animation time to 50sec. thats correct?